# Coding clarity of closure for load event

Tags: coding-style, coffeescript, closures

Is there are clear way to write this closure for the load event on line #4:

```
for i,item of m
  # add item once image loaded
  new_item = $("<img src='#{util.image_url(item, 'large')}' />")
  new_item.on 'load', ((item) => (=> @add_item(item)))(item)
  $("#preload-area").append(new_item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`do` loop](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

Something like this:

```
for i, item of m
  do (item) =>
    new_item = $("<img src='#{util.image_url(item, 'large')}' />")
    new_item.on 'load', => @add_item(item)
    $("#preload-area").append(new_item)
```

Comment: That didn't pass `this` properly; so I got `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'add_item'`

Comment: Do you want `do (item) =>`? All the arrows and nested functions